# How to create a new column in a pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to create a new column called "Continent" by grouping the values in another column called "Regions". The only codes that I managed to do are these:

`my_data.loc[(my_data ["Region"] ==  ("Australia and New Zealand")), "Continent"] = "Australia"`

But I am having trouble when there is more than one region for a continent. I have done this:

`my_data.loc[((my_data ["Region"] ==  ("Central and Eastern Europe")) & (my_data["Region"] == ("Western Europe"))), "Continent"] = "Europe"`

`my_data.loc[((my_data ["Region"] ==  ("Eastern Asia")) & (my_data["Region"] == ("Southeastern Asia"))), "Continent"] = "Asia" & (my_data["Region"] == ("Southern Asia "))), "Continent"] = "Asia"`

it seems like it does not recognize the code because when I execute this, it just appears "NaN" in the column, instead of the name of the continent.

Does anybody know what the problem is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is logic problem, never happens one condition `AND` another one, because test one column.

So need `|` for bitwise `OR`:

```
my_data.loc[((my_data ["Region"] ==  ("Central and Eastern Europe")) | (my_data["Region"] == ("Western Europe"))), "Continent"] = "Europe"
```

What working same like test by [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html):

```
my_data.loc[my_data ["Region"].isin(["Central and Eastern Europe", "Western Europe"]), "Continent"] = "Europe"
```